# Dictation and Emoji not working

Tags: voice-dictation, emoji

I am using OS X El Captain 10.11.6 (French edition).

For unknown reason, the function Start Dictation (Démarrer la dictée) et Emojis and Symbols (Emoji et Symboles) don't work anymore.

I followed the recommandation in this question:  [Dictation just stopped working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/243047). But, nothing works.

I have just updated to 10.11.6. But, it's not better.

What can I do? How to reset the settings?

NOTE:

- The microphone work (the bars are moving in de Preferences panel).
- When I choose Start Dictation (or fn fn) nothing appends (no microphone picture).
- When I choose Emojis and Symbols nothing appends too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this problem, it was fixed in a later macOS update.

Comment: You are right. I figured out that it was solved. Thanks.